# Browsing unanswered questions, how to scroll efficiently

Tags: feature-request

How can I reach e.g. page 348 of this endless list with less than 50 clicks?
When I read these things some pages per day, I can't seek to the last page or range I left some days before.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To *specifically* reach page 348:
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?page=348&tab=votes

Simply replace the number following *page=* in the URL.

Comment: Nice trick! thank you